# Add (+) a custom class object to a numeric object in Python

Tags: python, pandas, magic-methods

I know how to use magic methods to define mathematical operators in a custom class.

```
class CustomDataClass:
    
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
       
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.data)

    def __add__(self, obj):
        self.data+= obj
        return self 
a = CustomDataClass(1)
```

Then in the console you could do

```
print(a+1)

>>> 2
```

What if I want to do it in the opposite order?

```
print(1+a)
```

This would throw an error. I am curious how do I go about it. How did they do this in pandas for example?

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series(1)
print(1+a)

>>> 0    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Use `__radd__`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) which will be called if the l.h.s. `__add__` method returns `NotImplemented` (which is the case for `1 + a`).

Quoting the docs on `__r*__` methods:

> These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types. For instance, to evaluate the expression `x - y`, where `y` is an instance of a class that has an `__rsub__()` method, `y.__rsub__(x)` is called if `x.__sub__(y)` returns `NotImplemented`.